# ¿Evento click no funciona dentro de un html agregado en tiempo de ejecución con JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

Estoy agregando un html dentro de mi pagina principal en tiempo de ejecucion con JQuery el cual lo creo y lo agrego con el siguiente codigo

```
function show_agent_add(obj_agent, div_cont){
    var div_bar;
    $.get("view/bar_agent.html", function(data){
        div_bar = $(data);
        div_bar.find(".agent-data").html(obj_agent._getFirstName());        
        return false;
    });

}
```

por otro lado a este elemento agregado quiere acceder a su evento click desde jquery pero al depurar este no lo reconoce.

```
function show_detail_agent(){
    $(".content-agents .bar-agent-content .bar_agent").on("click", function(){
        //$(this).next().toggle();
        console.log("prueba");
    });
}
```

dentro del html tengo una estructura creada a partir de un div con una clase llamada .bar_agent.

Quisiera saber cual es la forma correcta de acceder al evento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes anexar el handler a `document` o a uno de los elementos de nivel superior que contengan el nuevo elemento, en efecto vas por la ruta correcta, si miras la documentación de [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) verás que acepta como segundo parámetro el selector que filtra los descendientes de los elementos que activan el evento:

```
$(document).on("click", ".content-agents .bar-agent-content .bar_agent", function(){
    //$(this).next().toggle();
    console.log("prueba");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

**Una vez enlazados asociados los eventos a elementos del DOM, si añades dinámicamente nuevos elementos, estos no quedan asociados a ese evento**, sino que debes asociarlo de manera forzada.

Si tienes el siguiente evento sobre los elementos "a" en el load de la página:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a').on('click', function(e){
        alert('click');
    });

});
```

Todo lo que añadas después dinámicamente no estará asociado a ese evento.

Te propongo lo siguiente, creas una función que asocie el evento:

```
function addAEvent(){

    $('a').unbind();

    $('a').on('click', function(e){
        alert('click');
    });    
}
```

Luego, en la carga del documento y tras agregar el elemento dinámico, llamas a la función `addAEvent()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    addAEvent();

    $.get("....", function(data){

        $('.div').html(data.loquesea);
        addAEvent();
    });

});
```

De esta forma te aseguras que siemrpe que añadas datos, se agrega el evento y ten en cuenta además, que al hacer el unbind(), limpias los eventos para que no haya multitud de ellos asociados al mismo elemento del DOM y luego de problemas.

Probablemente haya soluciones mejores, pero yo suelo usar esta y me funciona bien.